# Shorter way of saying "...had been the same as the ones now"?

Tags: word-choice

Example:

> I had a dream. In it, my surroundings **had been the same as the ones
>   now.**

Is there a shorter/simple way to write the **bolded** part?

Comment: "In it I was here."

Answer (score 2):

In it, my surroundings were the same as these.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are in the same exact location in the dream, as when you make the statement, you could say that: "In the dream, I found myself in familiar surroundings."